# backbone - Error: Cannot find module 'backbone'

Tags: node.js, backbone.js

I have pulled a project from github 
and tried running it, but got this error:

```
module.js:340
    throw err;
          ^
Error: Cannot find module 'backbone'
....
```

This is the first time that i use backbone, and node.js for that matter 
so i'm kinda lost .. 
can someone explain to me how to solve that error?

Answer (score 3):

You probably want to use Node's package manager NPM:

```
cd myProject
npm install backbone
```

Or use a global installation:

```
npm install -g backbone
```

And you should consider to inform yourself about [Node modules](http://nodejs.org/api/modules.html) and [Node's package management](http://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_addenda_package_manager_tipshowtonode.org/introduction-to-npm).

Answer (score 0):

Check and make sure you have backbone script available locally within your project folder. If not, then the best way for you to get it to work is install npm(node package manager) then install backbone module to your machine. That should solve the issue.